# Local site not loading after disabling two factor auth module and clearing cache in magento 2.4.1

Tags: cache, magento2.4.1, two-factor-authentication, flush

I have installed Magento 2.4.1 via composer install, then I tried to log in to the admin it asks for two-factor authentication, I have disabled the two-factor authentication using the command (bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth) and flushed the cache using (bin/magento cache:flush), after doing these when I try to access my site it gives a blank page(attached screenshot). [image: m2 site not loading]

Comment: check var/log/ for any exception

Comment: probably bin/magento setup:upgrade will help (in developer mode) or
bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento s:d:c && bin/magento s:s:d (in production mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of my senior, running the below command will fix the issue and makes the site to appear.

cmd: **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

in 2.4.1 after enabling a module we need to do compile.